# Using PHP include inside PHP statement

Tags: php, iframe

I'm building a php driven website which has this code:

```
<?php
if($content_media == "php"){
$media_file = "".include("photos/media/$page_year/$page_id.php")."";
}
else if($content_media == "jpg"){
$media_file = "<img src=\"photos/media/$page_year/$page_id.jpg\" width=\"440px\" />";
}
?>
<?php
if($content_media == "0"){
$display_media = "";
}else{
$display_media = "
<div class=\"contentSpace\"></div>
<div class=\"content\">
    <div class=\"contentImageTop contentImageTop440\"></div>
    <div class=\"contentImageMiddle contentImageMiddle440\">
        $media_file
    </div>
    <div class=\"contentImageBottom contentImageBottom440\"></div>
</div>
";
}
?>
<html>
<?php echo $display_media; ?>
</html>
```

When I run the page, it doesn't run/show the `171107093918.php` file, which in this case includes the text for an **embeded google map**.

Any idea whaere I'm going wrong, or how to fix the code to display the IFrame code from the php file?

Comment: Right now it's just text... I think that hint should be enough?

Comment: Hint? Care to elabarate? I tried it with '<?php include(\"media/2017/171107093918.php\"); ?>' and that gave me the same result!

Answer (score -1):

change to

```
$display_media = "
<div class=\"contentSpace\"></div>
<div class=\"content\">
    <div class=\"contentImageTop contentImageTop440\"></div>
    <div class=\"contentImageMiddle contentImageMiddle440\">
        ".include("media/2017/171107093918.php")."
    </div>
    <div class=\"contentImageBottom contentImageBottom440\"></div>
</div>
";
```

in response to the edit: my guess is that the script that you are including `echo`'s (or is plain html), so it will show up where you include it. To mitigate the issue, make sure your included script `return`s the string, as opposed to printing it out right

Comment: Thanks. The map is now showing, but in the wrong place. Please take a look at my ammended question to see how I'm trying to load up the map/php file.

Comment: Thanks, but can you please edit it for my original question. I'm loading up Jpg, Gif and MP3 as well as the PHP file. All the others work fine, just can't get the php inclusion file to echo out.

Comment: Added the JPG code to show what I'm trying to echo in `$display_media`

Comment: can you maybe add the file you are having issues with, kinda hard to figure out whats wrong without the file

Comment: The file just includes the text for a basic google map. Full code = `<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2386.273309018526!2d-2.480028634164546!3d53.26672247996241!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x487af8b9c5ef4a55%3A0x896ba434e9029c30!2sWorks+Ln%2C+Lostock+Gralam%2C+Northwich+CW9+7NW!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1500371938214" width="440" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: my edit stands: do `<?php return '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2‌​386.273309018526!2d-‌​2.480028634164546!3d‌​53.26672247996241!2m‌​3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i‌​1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m‌​3!1m2!1s0x487af8b9c5‌​ef4a55%3A0x896ba434e‌​9029c30!2sWorks+Ln%2‌​C+Lostock+Gralam%2C+‌​Northwich+CW9+7NW!5e‌​0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v15‌​00371938214" width="440" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'` that way you will be able to include it as a php string

Comment: Ok. I've added the `return` statement, but the map is still showing at the top. The problem with the edit is that you've edited the line inside `$display_media`, where I really need an edit for line `$media_file`

Comment: you probably did not add the string character. Notice the `'` in `<?php return '<iframe...` before the iframe tag

Comment: I added the `'`. And I added one at the end `' ?>`